# How to send PNG image from client to server in Flask?

Tags: ajax, flask

I want to send a PNG image from the client to the server.
I tried using ajax as follows:

```
var saveImg = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json",
     url: "/save_image",
     data: {"data":JSON.stringify(String(saveImg))},
     success: null
     });
```

The renderer variable is a three.js WebGLRenderer and the produced image data seem correct.

This gave me the data on the flask server as POST request where I handled it as follows:

```
@app.route("/save_image", methods=["GET","POST"])
def save_image():
    print(request.__dict__) # png data arrives as unusable string
```

The data arrives as unusable string that cannot be recovered to binary form via e.g. bytesarray. I feel like I am doing something seriously wrong here.
But the simple

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "image/png",
                    url: "/save_image",
                    data: saveImg
                });
```

Doesn't arrive at the server at all, i.e.:

```
@app.route("/save_image", methods=["GET","POST"])
def save_image():
    print(request.__dict__) # no 'data' key/val pair arrived
```

I feel like there should be a *very simple* way to do it, however I couldn't really figure it out. Any help/links to relevant documentation is appreciated.